# Extracting information out of a dictionary...An alternative to if/else statements

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```C#
Dictionary<string, DateTime> Seasons = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>
{
    { "WINTER_START", Date1},
    { "WINTER_END", Date2 },
    { "SUMMER_START", Date3 },
    { "SUMMER_END", Date4 }
};
```

Let's say I have today's date `var today = DateTime.Today.Date` and I want to know if today's date falls in winter or summer. I've done this using an If/Else statement, but something inside me tells me there is a better way..

```c#
string currentSeason = "";

if (today >= Seasons["WINTER_START"] && today <= Seasons["WINTER_END"])
{
    currentSeason = "WINTER";
} 
else if (today >= Seasons["SUMMER_START"] && today <= Seasons["SUMMER_END"])
{
    currentSeason = "SUMMER";
}
```

Comment: How about a "Range" structure with start/end and then a `Dictionary<string, Range> { { "Summer", summerRange }, { "Winter", winterRange } }`? Bonus if "Range" has a "Contains" method. Then you could do `currentSeason = Seasons.First(s => s.Value.Contains(today)).Select(s => s.Key)`

Comment: How do these fair from a performance perspective?! Say this piece of code was going to run millions of times per day on different records, do I really need to create and store a Range object?

Comment: Hopefully you *create* (and "store"?) the `Range` object only once. How fast it is depends on how fast the `Contains` method is. But that should also be only a `return today >= start && today <= end;` so basically no difference at all. -- But see @BoredomOverload answer for a nice implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you are locked down to using a Dictionary for this, but i think this is a friendlier version and how i would've tackled the problem:

```
void Main()
{
    var seasons = new List<Season>
    {
        new Season("Winter", Date1, Date2),
        new Season("Summer", Date3, Date4)
    };

    var today = DateTime.Today;

    // null if no matching season was found
    string currentSeason = seasons.FirstOrDefault(season => season.InSeason(today))?.Name;
}

public class Season
{
    public Season(string name, DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        Name = name;
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    public bool InSeason(DateTime input)
    {
        return input >= Start && input <= End;
    }
}
```

Also a minor remark: `Current_Season` is not a good variable name for a local variable. [This](https://www.dofactory.com/reference/csharp-coding-standards) might help you improve your naming.